# Testar UPDATE no Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

A ideia é fazer uma busca com o resultado do ANTES, executar o UPDATE com as devidas alterações e executar uma nova busca com o DEPOIS, então desfazer todas as alterações, um teste para UPDATE.

```
SELECT id_evento, id_statusevento FROM syo_evento WHERE id_evento = 771678;
UPDATE syo_evento SET id_statusevento = 'CANCELADO' WHERE id_evento = 771678;
SELECT id_evento, id_statusevento FROM syo_evento WHERE id_evento = 771678;
ROLLBACK
```

Funciona, mas no Datastudio 4.7 só recebo o resultado do primeiro SELECT, enquanto no pgAdmin 3 não recebo resultado "Query result with 1 row discarded.", existe alguma forma de fazer o que preciso ?

Comment: Faltou usar o `begin` antes to `update` para iniciar uma transação.

Answer (score -1):

Consegui algum resultado usando o Datastudio, não tenho interesse em outra ferramento, uso mais de um tipo banco e o datastudio me permite acessar todos eles.

---

```
WITH alterados AS ( UPDATE syo_evento SET id_statusevento = 'CANCELADO' WHERE id_evento = 771678 RETURNING * )
SELECT '1-ANTES' as tipo, id_evento, id_statusevento FROM syo_evento WHERE id_evento = 771678
UNION ALL
SELECT '2-DEPOIS', id_evento, id_statusevento FROM alterados;
ROLLBACK
```

---

Não sei se é o ideal, é possível que o `WITH` possua limitações de quantidade de dados assim como há no Sql Server, se tiverem algum ideia melhor fiquem a vontade, obrigado.

Comment: Acho que você precisa ler isso [aqui](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ecpg-sql-set-autocommit.html) e isso [aqui](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-transactions.html).

Comment: @Lacobus, não entendi como isto me ajuda, preciso ver o "antes e depois" do update, deverei usar como uma prova real para updates maiores, sendo melhor no datastudio, pois posso trabalhar em vários tipos de bancos. Se quiser exemplificar em resposta fique a vontade, obrigado.